# How to get chat history using agsXMPP in C#

Tags: c#, xmpp, agsxmpp

How to get chat history using `XMPP`.

I am using the `agsXMPP` framework for `C#`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't.

Both `agsXMPP` and its paid version `MatriX XMPP` do not support this functionality.
The message archiving management is defined in the `XEP-0136` XMPP extension.

According to some old threads [here](http://forum.ag-software.net/thread/1568-Retrieve-chat-history) and [here](http://forum.ag-software.net/thread/1757-How-to-retrieve-conversation-history-of-users) on the AG forum this extension is "huge and still on the todo list".

You can however add your own functionality to the SDK to manage this. It's quite straight forward.

Comment: XEP-0136 is implemented in MatriX for a while now, but not in agsXMPP. 
And as you said, for extensions which are not supported its very easy to write your own extensions either for agsXMPP or MatriX